# Get Type of Collection using Roslyn

Tags: vb.net, roslyn

Using Roslyn for VB.Net I can get the Type of an Expression using the code below.

```
Dim ExpressionType As TypeInfo = SemanticModel.GetTypeInfo(ForEachStatement.Expression)
```

If the expression is a collection (List, Dictionary, Array, Collection...) how can I find out what is in the collection? For the example below I want to find DocumentIdAndRoot

```
Dim docs As List(Of DocumentIdAndRoot) = Await RemoveParameterAsync(document, parameter, root, cancellationToken)
```

Answer (score 2):

If your question is specific to `foreach`, then you should use `SemanticModel.GetForEachStatementInfo()`, which returns a [`ForEachStatementInfo`](http://source.roslyn.codeplex.com/#Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp/Compilation/ForEachStatementInfo.cs,55c404668b282991) with all the necessary information.

Comment: Thanks this worked perfectly. For some reason I can't make it answered.

Comment: Some collections are arrays and others are things like lists. For Arrays you need to end the type with () but for Lists you don't. I don't see any information that would tell me if I need to add the ().

Answer (score 1):

What you could do is take the TypeInfo you get, and look at the ImplementedInterfaces property. One of those would be IEnumerable or ICollection, and from there you could look at what the generic parameter is.

If you do have a ForEach involved somewhere, you're still better off using Tamas' approach, since that will correctly implement the language rules there.